# How to find lower bound , upper bound , greatest lower bound ,lowest upperbound from this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

[image: hess diagaram]

Problem :
Relation $R$  from the following sets :
$ xRy \iff x|y $

$A=(1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18,24,27,36,4854,72,81,108,144,162,216,324,432,648,1296)$

Question A : draw the hess diagram

Question B  :

Find ub,lub,lb,glb from the following sets :

$B = (8,12,18,27)$

$C=\{12,18,36,72,108,216\}$

$D=\{6,12,18,24,36,54\}$

$E=\{6,12,36,72\}$

Now my question :

1. Is my hess diagram correct ????
2. How I can find the lub ,ub , lb ,glb ??

Comment: Your question does not provide a definition of the relation.

Comment: o yea sorry . gonna edit it

Comment: What's the problem with the bounds? Do you know the definition?

Comment: i know the definition but im still confuse how to  implement it in the problem  like this one .

Comment: Your Hess diagram looks pretty good. To find upper and lower bounds you can use your diagram but it is easier to use your relation. If $xRy$ is defined by $x|y$ what do you think the an upper bound would be? How about the least upper bound?

Comment: let use example B as an example . B = {8,12,18,27} so the lower bound are {9,6,4,3,2,1} ?

Comment: $9$ is not a lower bound for the set because it does not divide $8$ or $12$. The lower bounds will be the common divisors and the greatest lower bound will be the ___?

Comment: if so then   3 can isnot   a lowerbound ? since it doesnt divide 8 . the greates lower bound  will be 1 ?

Comment: You got it. Upper bounds work the same way but we use multiples instead of divisors.

Comment: i see , so the lub is 216 right ?